# SQL: if WHERE XY not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a WordPress installation. Ive got over 1000 posts, with custom fields. The problem is, Wordpress creates the custom field in the database only when you save the post for the first time, but i want to fill these fields, no matter if they exist or not, when they don't exist, i need to create them.

I tried with this, and of course, its working:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = '9.979348999999957'
WHERE meta_key ='longitude' AND post_id = '486';
```

Here is the question: What can i do, if the meta_key 'longitude' dosen't exist in the database?

Comment: Could you do a select initially to see if it exists? If not, create it.

Comment: This is just bad practice to create table field on-the-fly...

Comment: According to [wp_postmeta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta) table description there's no unique index for combination of `post_id` and `meta_key` fields. If there was you could simply use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Are you ready to alter database?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the presence of 'longitude'

```
try this: $sql = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("Select * from wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key ='longitude'");

echo $sql;
```

This will let you know whether a record with that meta_key exists in database or not

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES (486, 'longitude', '9.979348999999957')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = '9.979348999999957';
```

Assuming the primary key for `wp_postmeta` is `(post_id, meta_key`).

---

I [see now](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta) that it's not. In that case, you can insert first and then update.

```
-- insert first
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta(post_id, metakey)
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, 'longitude'
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON (p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'longitude')
WHERE m.post_id IS NULL;

-- update later
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = '9.979348999999957'
WHERE meta_key = 'longitude' AND post_id = '486';
```

Comment: won't work, because there's no unique index on these fields. Check [wp_postmeta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta) description

Comment: @mente Yeah, I saw it. Thanks. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: In fact it's possible in 1 query. Check my answer. Though it's a little bit cryptic

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is even possible without unique index of `post_id` and `meta_key` combination:

```
  INSERT 
      INTO 
  wp_postmeta 
       (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
  (SELECT 
       wm.meta_id, nd.post_id, "longitude", nd.new_longitude
   FROM 
      (SELECT 
           456 as post_id, "new cool longitude here" as new_longitude) nd
       LEFT JOIN 
           wp_postmeta wm ON nd.post_id = wm.post_id AND wm.meta_key = 
                  "longitude") 
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = VALUES(meta_value)
```

In order to change values simply update 456 and "longitude" in this query to your values.

## How this query works?

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` allows to perform insert of new row or update existing if there's duplicate of unique/primary index. More info about this form of query can be found in [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Due to lack of unique index on `post_id`, `meta_key` combination the only unique index left is `meta_id`. So the idea is to use `meta_id` as duplicate index instead. Let's have a look at select query:

```
  SELECT 
       wm.meta_id, nd.post_id, "location", nd.new_location
  FROM 
       (SELECT 456 as post_id, "new cool location here" as new_location) nd
  LEFT JOIN 
       wp_postmeta wm ON nd.post_id = wm.post_id AND wm.meta_key = 
           "location"
```

Main point of this query is to find existing primary index of row `meta_id` or use `NULL` if nothing is found.
Example of result if there's existing data in DB:

```
  +---------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
  | meta_id | post_id | longitude | new_longitude          |
  +---------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
  |       4 |     456 | longitude | new cool location here |
  +---------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if there's not:

```
  +---------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
  | meta_id | post_id | longitude | new_longitude          |
  +---------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
  |    NULL |     456 | longitude | new cool location here |
  +---------+---------+-----------+------------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Don't get confused with complexity of this query: performance of this query is the same as select + update combination.

**WARNING** This sort of query loses portability between databases. `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` is MySQL extension to SQL standard and supported only by MySQL